# Understanding why deadlock happens in this implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, deadlock

I am new to multithreading, and I came across this example:

```
public class TestThread {
   public static Object Lock1 = new Object();
   public static Object Lock2 = new Object();

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      ThreadDemo1 T1 = new ThreadDemo1();
      ThreadDemo2 T2 = new ThreadDemo2();
      T1.start();
      T2.start();
   }

   private static class ThreadDemo1 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1...");
            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...");
            synchronized (Lock2) {
               System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   }
   private static class ThreadDemo2 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock2) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 2...");
            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Waiting for lock 1...");
            synchronized (Lock1) {
               System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

This causes the following sample output:

```
Thread 1: Holding lock 1...
Thread 2: Holding lock 2...
Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...
Thread 2: Waiting for lock 1...
```

i.e, there is a deadlock. However, if we change the order of locks obtained in the second thread so that it looks like this now:

```
public class TestThread {
   public static Object Lock1 = new Object();
   public static Object Lock2 = new Object();

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      ThreadDemo1 T1 = new ThreadDemo1();
      ThreadDemo2 T2 = new ThreadDemo2();
      T1.start();
      T2.start();
   }

   private static class ThreadDemo1 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1...");
            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...");
            synchronized (Lock2) {
               System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   }
   private static class ThreadDemo2 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1...");
            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Waiting for lock 2...");
            synchronized (Lock2) {
               System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

It works as expected, and a sample output looks like this:

```
Thread 1: Holding lock 1...
Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...
Thread 1: Holding lock 1 & 2...
Thread 2: Holding lock 1...
Thread 2: Waiting for lock 2...
Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening in the first one that is causing the deadlock, and why does the change in second code fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a possible scenario for the first case:

Thread 1 acquires `Lock1` and goes to sleep for 10 milliseconds. Now Thread 2 acquires `Lock2` and goes to sleep for 10 milliseconds.

Now Thread 1 tries to acquire `Lock2`, but can't get it since it's acquired by Thread 2, while Thread 2 tries to get `Lock1` which is locked by Thread 1.

In the second case, let's assume the first thread is picked to run. It gets `Lock1`, while the other thread is blocked because it's trying to get `Lock1` as well. Now thread 1 goes to sleep, and proceed to the second (nested) synchronized block. It tries to get it (because it's still free) - now he got **2** locks. The other thread is still blocked.

Only after it finishes execution, it releases **both** locks (since it exit the synchronized block), and now the JVM is free to decide which thread to pick, but it doesn't really matter, the same logic happens.

Comment: Thanks. I can now understand the first case. But the second case is still a bit hazy. So thread 2 is waiting for first lock. As soon as it is released by thread 1, what happens then?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger Thread 2 gets it and begin the execution of the first statement under the synchronized block.

Comment: Which is `System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...");`? And it releases lock 2, which is acquired by thread 1, and it prints `System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1 & 2...");` ?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger Exactly.

Comment: Why does second thread release lock 2 after acquiring lock 1?

Comment: @AttitudeMonger Because it exits the first synchronized block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110103/discussion-between-attitudemonger-and-maroun-maroun).

Answer (score 2):

What you see here is lock ordering, a common method for deadlock prevention.

In your first case, consider the following order of execution with the current instruction pointers located at the marked location for each thread:

```
  Thread 1:
     obtain lock 1
===>
     obtain lock 2
  Thread 2:
     obtain lock 2
===>
     obtain lock 1
```

Now, thread 1 tries to obtain lock 2 next, but cannot as lock 2 is held by thread 2. And thread 2 tries to obtain lock 1 next, but cannot, because it is held by thread 1. This is a classical circular resource dependency and hence results in deadlock.

A global method to prevent this is to make sure all locks have a *total* order and locks are always acquired in that total order.

The proof that this works is trivial: Because all lock dependencies are "downward" in the total order, you cannot have lock cycles.

Answer (score 1):

Well in your first piece of code the first thread is holding `Lock1` and the second is holding `Lock2` obviously. Then they try to grab each other's locks but they fail because the other locks are already being held by the other thread so a deadlock is created.

In the second piece of code however, the second thread isn't holding `Lock2` and is blocked out of anything until the first thread releases the first lock. The first thread will release the first lock after it also grabs the second one, as seen by your output.